# simplest way to echo one value of one row

Tags: php

I have this simple query

```
$qry = "select MAX(image_id) from tpf_images";
$res = $pdo->query($qry);
```

the result of which is just one number. What is the quickest, simplest way to echo that number out with php?

Thanks

Comment: did you try using `echo`?

Comment: I know how to use echo, normally i echo many rows of data using a foreach loop. But there must be a simpler way when it is just one number being retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thnk fetchColumn() is what you are looking for. It retrieve the next row first column. Since you are having only one row and one column, it will return the first row and first column value. If there is no row returned from database, it will return FALSE.

```
echo $pdo->query($qry)->fetchColumn();
```